# Confine validations to controls in gridview while updating(using command field edit,update,cancel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am able to provide validations for the controls in grid view but those validations are also applied to the controls in the form.

My question is how can those validations can be confined to controls in gridview only?

i am using inbuilt commandfield (edit,update,cancel) as edit button. when i set property causevalidations to true for the commandfiled, it triggers validation not only to controls in  gridview but also to the rest of the form.

coudl you help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify [ValidationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) for the controls in the GridView(e.g. VG_Update).

- [Partitioning the Validation Controls into Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb426882.aspx#aspnett19_vldcntredtuics_topic7)

Comment: Hey Tim Schmelter, i could not vote up as i still havent enough reputation but your answer worked for me.

Comment: @Uneverno: Even more important than upvoting is accepting answers, so that they get closed and don't get pushed from time to time. Here are more informations on "how accepting answers works": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 (as i've already linked above ;))

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the help and gudiance. thanks for your patience.